# I am trying to make a GUI for a app I am working on but when I try print a global variable I get an error. Why?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI using tkinter for a app of my. but when I use print on a global variable I get an error that its not defined. Why? (the print is to check the value of the variable) also its have to be a global because I am using it more outside the function. also I tried to change it to message_here = enter_mess_here.get()()

```
enter_mess = tk.Label(root, text = 'enter below the message')
enter_mess.pack() 
enter_mess_here = tk.Entry(root)
enter_mess_here.pack() 
def getting_message():
    global message_here
    message_here = enter_mess_here.get()
    done_procces_mess = tk.Label(root, text = "message got procced!")
    done_procces_mess.pack() 
get_mess = tk.Button(root, text = "procces message", command = getting_message)
get_mess.pack() 
print(message_here)
```

Comment: From experience, I wouldn't recommend using global variables. Try adding a parameter to the function.

Comment: Your `print` is executed before `getting_message`. You attach `getting_message` to the button click but not execute it until the button is clicked. On the other hand `print` is executed when you start your script.

Comment: Why dont you define your variable `message_here` in beforehand instead of using the `global` statement

Comment: this is what I asked. how do I defined it? I need it for outside the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the global variable is only defined when the function is ran. You only pass a reference to the function into tk.Button (that is, the function without () at the end).

For example:

```
def global_test():
    global x
    x = 5
y = global_test
print(x)
```

Outputs `NameError: name 'x' is not defined`

Whereas:

```
def global_test():
    global x
    x = 5
y = global_test()
print(x)
```

Outputs `5`

To use it in Tkinter, I would wrap up the functionality in a class. That way you can run the button and remember the message without using global variables.

```
import tkinter as tk

class TkinterMessageBox():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.enter_mess = tk.Label(self.root, text = 'enter below the message')
        self.enter_mess.pack() 
        self.enter_mess_here = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.enter_mess_here.pack()
        self.get_mess = tk.Button(self.root, text = "procces message", command = self.getting_message)
        self.get_mess.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def getting_message(self):
        self.message_here = self.enter_mess_here.get()
        done_procces_mess = tk.Label(self.root, text = "message got procced!")
        done_procces_mess.pack() 
        self.root.destroy()
        

message_box = TkinterMessageBox()

print(message_box.message_here)
```

Example usage is in [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#a-simple-hello-world-program).

Comment: I can't do that with this code. if I try this I get error 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @Heag I would suggest looking at what a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is. Your code above doesn't run on its own which makes it harder to help.

Comment: how do I put this in my currant windows? I am new to making GUI

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code it's hard to tell. Check out [python classes](https://realpython.com/lessons/classes-python/) and perhaps create a new question as I believe the original question has been answered.

Comment: Please mark correct if you agree. I've also added a link to the documentation example application.

Comment: OK. I will make a new question Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Move `print(message_here)` into the `getting_message` callback function of the button, and remove `global message_here`.